# Корректная работа с памятью С++

Tags: c++

**Вопрос (A):**

```
void Fun(void){  
    int *a = new int[10];  
    int *b = new int[10];  
    CopyMemory(b, a, 10);  
}
```

Если в дальнейшем мы не используем массив `a[]`:

1. Мы должны освободить память: `delete[] a`?
2. А если вместо 1 напишем `a = NULL`?
3. И если не выполним ни 1, ни 2 а просто выйдем из функции `Fun`?

**Вопрос (B):**

```
void Fun(int **c){  
    int *a = new int[10];  
    int *b = new int[100];  
    CopyMemory(b, a, 10);
    *c = b;  
    delete[] a;
}
```

Так будет правильно?

**Вопрос (С):**

```
 int *a = new int[10];  
 int *b = new int[100];
 CopyMemory(b, a, 10);
 delete[] a;  
 a = b;
```

Здесь всё корректно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильный ответ 1. В C++ нет сборщика мусора, поэтому вся ответственность за освобождение памяти лежит на разработчике.
2-ой ответ неправильный, т.к. a - это просто указатель, т.е. переменная хранящая адрес начала выделенного блока памяти и изменение указателя никак не повлияет на саму память.
Стоит отметить, что в С++ хорошим тоном считается использование умных указателей - классов оберток над указателями заботящихся об освобождении памяти (например auto_ptr из стандартной библиотеки).

Answer (score 1):

Код обрамите соответствующими тэгами, пожалуйста. Абсолютно нечитабельно получилось.

1. Вообще-то да.
2. Напишем, так и напишем. Программа или выкинет exception, или будет хромать дальше.
3. Потеряем 20*sizeof(int) байтов.

Ровно для того, чтобы не было таких проблем придумали умные указатели. Они объединяют лучшее из стекового и динамического выделения памяти. Стековая память автоматически чистится при выходе за область видимости, а динамика позволяет выделять большие объемы памяти, т.к. стека всегда не хватает. Таким образом, создавая умный указатель на стеке, мы потом можно не беспокоиться о том, нужно ли чистить память. Как только указатель грохнется - освободится вся указуемая им память. Правда, при этом нужно быть аккуратным с присваиваниями и копированиями указателей. Т.к. при этом на одну область памяти будет указывать несколько указателей. И тогда могут происходить всякие неприятные вещи. Поэтому в дальнейшем происходит дифференциация умных указателей. Есть "сильные", которые владеют объектами, а есть "слабые", которые не участвуют в подсчете количества ссылок.

PS:

> int *a=new[10];

так писать некорректно. Наверное. Т.к. new принимает тип. Т.е. нам нужно переписать это как:

> int *a=new int [10];// выделить память под массив на 10 int'ов

PPS:

> int *a=new[10];
> int *b=new[100];
> delete[] a;
> a=b;

Ага. А потом почти наверняка сделаете

```
delete [] a;
delete [] b; //FAIL!?
```

Comment: Хватит прикалываться! :) Понятно что после new идёт тип! (забыл написать) Вопрос (C) остаётся в силе!

Comment: А скажите-ка - что мешает сделать собственный класс my_super_puper_array, где реализовать необходимые Вам функциональности? Ну, или использовать какой-либо стандартный шаблонный тип. См. в сторону STL и boost. Наверняка ведь есть что-то более удачное, чем изобретать велосипед.

Comment: Когда изобритаешь велосипед начинаешь понимать не только как крутить педали, но ещё и как подкачать колесо! :)

Comment: Функция изменения размерности массива с сохранением данных:


Void RedimPreserve (double **Array, long OldSize, long NewSize){
       double * tmpArray = new double[OldSize];
       CopyMemory(tmpArray , * Array ,OldSize * sizeof(double));
       delete[] * Array;
       * Array = tmpArray;}


В конце концов я считаю такой код должен работать оптимально!? Или есть другие мнентя!?

Answer (score 1):

(A) память теряется, как воспользоваться результатом работы Fun() непонятно.

(B) не мой взгляд правильно. Первый (далее неиспользуемый) массив освобождается, адрес его копии передается из функции и может далее использоваться.

(С) не понимаю, что Вы хотите. Оба указателя (a и b) указывают на копию первоначального a[], ну и что дальше?

Comment: (C) - Увеличение размера массива с сохранением того что в нём было!

 (аналог функции VB Redim Preserve a(0 to 99))

Comment: realloc() чем не нравится ?

Comment: Ну... незнаю, и вообще в каких случаях имеет смысл использовать не new а malloc, это же C-шная библиотека!? И она же вызывается оператором new (C++)

Comment: new - вызывает конструктор. malloc - не вызывает. Поэтому new в ООП-коде предпочтителен, т.к. мы получаем готовый для работы объект. А при выделении памяти с malloc'ом придется еще колдовать.

Comment: А если я выделяю память под массив оператором new и затем мне необходимо изменить размерность сохраняя данные могу ли я использовать realoc() или нужно будет ещё что то нашёптывать!? :)

Comment: <i> могу ли я использовать realoc() </i><p>
очень сомнительно<p>
<i>выделяю память под массив оператором new</i><p>
Короче, если у Вас массив double'ов или int'ов (т.е. элементы базового встроенного типа) - согласен, проще использовать malloc/free/realloc. Если массив объектов - лучше new/delete